# Bulk saving complex objects SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
association_table = Table("association_table",
                          Base.metadata,
                          Column("show_id", Integer(), ForeignKey("show_times.id"), primary_key=True),
                          Column("theater_id", Integer(), ForeignKey("theaters.id")))

association_table2 = Table("association_table2",
                           Base.metadata,
                           Column("show_id", Integer(), ForeignKey("show_times.id"), primary_key=True),
                           Column("movie_id", Integer(), ForeignKey("movies.id")))



class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = "movies"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(), unique=True)
    plot = Column(String())
    duration = Column(String())
    rating = Column(String())
    trailer = Column(String())
    imdb = Column(String())
    poster = Column(String())
    summary = Column(String())

class Theater(Base):
    __tablename__ = "theaters"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    zip_code = Column(String())
    city = Column(String())
    state = Column(String())
    address = Column(String())
    phone_number = Column(String())


class Showtime(Base):
    __tablename__ = "show_times"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date())
    theaterz = relationship("Theater", secondary=association_table)
    moviez = relationship("Movie", secondary=association_table2)
    showtimes = Column(String())
```

supposing we have  movie objects:

```
movie_1 = Movie(title="Cap Murica",
              plot="Cap punches his way to freedom",
              duration="2 hours")

movie_2 = Movie(title="Cap Murica 22222",
              plot="Cap punches his way to freedom again",
              duration="2 hours")
```

and a theater object:

```
theater = Theater(name="Regal Cinemas",
                  zip_code="00000",
                  city="Houston",
                  state="TX")
```

how do we bulk save this into the `show_times` Model?

I've tried doing this:

```
movies = [movie_1, movie_2] # these movie objects are from the code snippet above

show_times = Showtime(date="5/19/2016",
                      theaterz=[theater],
                      moviez=movies)
session.add(show_times)
session.commit()
```

hurray the above works. but when i do it in bulk like this:

```
showtime_lists = [show_time1, show_time2, showtime3] # these are basically just the same show time objects as above

session.bulk_save_objects(showtime_lists)
session.commit()
```

it doesn't fail but the data also doesn't get persisted to the database.

I mean is there an alternative to adding each `show_time` to the session individually? A bulk insert would be better but I don't get why the data doesn't get persisted if done that way.

Comment: Does it fail to persist completely, or do the `ShowTime` instances themselves get persisted, but no related data. Apparently [`bulk_save_objects`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_save_objects) is quite a low level API and ignores a lot of stuff, like relationships. Have you had a look at [`Session.add_all`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add_all)?

Comment: @IljaEverilä I guess I failed to mention it. but yes `Showtime` get persisted but the `relationships` get ignored

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[`Session.bulk_save_objects()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_save_objects) is too low level API for your use case, which is persisting multiple model objects *and their relationships*. The documentation is clear on this:

> **Warning**
>
> The bulk save feature allows for a lower-latency INSERT/UPDATE of rows at the expense of most other unit-of-work features. Features such as object management, **relationship handling**, and SQL clause support are **silently omitted** in favor of raw INSERT/UPDATES of records.
>
> Please read the list of caveats at [Bulk Operations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/persistence_techniques.html#bulk-operations) before using this method, and fully test and confirm the functionality of all code developed using these systems.

You should use [`Session.add_all()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add_all) to add a collection of instances to the session. It will handle the instances one at a time, but that is the price you have to pay for advanced features such as relationship handling.

So, instead of

```
session.bulk_save_objects(showtime_lists)
session.commit()
```

do

```
session.add_all(showtime_lists)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Well thats what I get for just scanning the docs and not thoroughly reading them.

I appreciate you highlighting that part. I was even planning to do this via using the `SQLAlchemy core` but seeing as the relationships are quite complex.. well... `Session.add_all` it is

Answer (score -3):

You can assign ids manually:

1. Get a [write lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html) on the table
2. Find the highest existing id
3. Manually generate an increasing sequence of ids

Instead of locking the table, you might be able to increment the id sequence in the database to ["reserve" a block of ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411384/reserving-mysql-auto-incremented-ids).

You'll have to insert in the proper order to avoid foreign key violations (or defer the constraints if your engine allows this).