# Flask Sqlalchemy add multiple row

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask-restful this is
My class I want to insert

```
class OrderHistoryResource(Resource):

    model = OrderHistoryModel
    schema = OrderHistorySchema
    order = OrderModel
    product = ProductModel

    def post(self):
        value = req.get_json()
        data = cls.schema(many=True).load(value)  
        data.insert()
```

In my model

```
def insert(self):
    db.session.add(self)
    db.session.commit()
```

schema

```
from config.ma import ma
from model.orderhistory import OrderHistoryModel

class OrderHistorySchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderHistoryModel
        include_fk = True
```

Example Data I want to insert

```
[
    {
        "quantity":99,
        "flaskSaleStatus":true,
        "orderId":"ORDER_64a79028d1704406b6bb83b84ad8c02a_1568776516",
        "proId":"PROD_9_1568779885_64a79028d1704406b6bb83b84ad8c02a"
     },
     {
        "quantity":89,
        "flaskSaleStatus":true,
        "orderId":"ORDER_64a79028d1704406b6bb83b84ad8c02a_1568776516",
        "proId":"PROD_9_1568779885_64a79028d1704406b6bb83b84ad8c02a"
     }
]
```

this is what i got after insert method has started

```
TypeError: insert() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)
```

or there is another way to do this action?

Comment: You seem to have a few strange features in this code. You don't need to define `post` as a class method - and inside that method you've passed `self` in the function definition but use `cls` to reach the schema, seems like this should error. I can't see the rest of the code but assume `OrderHistorySchema` is just a marshmallow schema? Which means `data` isn't an instance of your model therefore might be a different `insert` method? Please show model and schema classes.

Comment: sorry for not clear question this happended cause i changed schema() to schema(many=True) when Insert method started (in model) seem like it didn't see any parameters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edited - released marshmallow-sqlalchemy loads directly to instance**

You need to loop through the `OrderModel` instances in your list.

You can then use `add_all` to add the `OrderModel` objects to the session, then bulk update - see [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add_all)

Should be something like:

```
db.session.add_all(data)
db.session.commit()
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338047/bulk-saving-complex-objects-sqlalchemy) for brief discussion on why `add_all` is best when you have complex ORM relationships.

Also - not sure you need to have all your models/schemas as class variables, it's fine to have them imported (or just present in the same file, as long as they're declared before the resource class).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `insert` on list cause `data` is list of model `OrderHistoryModel` instances.

Also `post` method doesn't need to be `classmethod` and you probably had an error there as well.

Since `data` is list of model instances you can use `db.session.add_all` method to add them to session in bulk.

```
    def post(self):
        value = req.get_json()
        data = self.schema(many=True).load(value)
        db.session.add_all(data)
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: thanks ,but I don't want to loop them before insert